Avoid downtime during deployment with Serverless Github Action
I'm using https://github.com/serverless/github-action to deploy my NodeJS functions.
When running, its process is the following:
Disabling function: function01
Disabling function: function02
...

Bundling with Webpack...
Fetch dependency
Zip function: /github/workspace/backend/.webpack/function01
Zip function: /github/workspace/backend/.webpack/function02
...

Setting artifact for function
Uploading service function01.zip file to S3
Uploading service function02.zip file to S3
...

UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Function - function01
UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Function - function02
...

It takes about 8-9 minutes from start to finish. During most of this time, the functions are down.
What would be a workaround?
I am thinking of deploying the functions one by one, but I don't see such an option with this Serverless Github Action pipeline
